# Conditional formatting (Iconsets) based on delay

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here's the data of my Excel file:

[image]

Schedule variance is <=0 if the task is started/finished sooner or on time and will be >=1 if there's a delay in start/finish.

Now I want to use Excel's conditional formatting and apply iconsets to the Status column:

- Green flag if both start and finish are on track (<=0)
- Yellow flag if either start/finish went off track (>0)
- Red flag if both went off track (>0)

I'm not new to Excel and CF, but I can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you want to display Icon Set not just plain background color in cells. If so, try the following solution.

See the screenshot. Sample data is in Cells D4:E10, which is your sample variance data.

In F4 put the following formula and drag it down along the length of table.

```
=IF(AND(D4<=0,E4<=0),3,IF(OR(D4<=0,E4<=0),2,IF(AND(D4>0,E4>0),1)))
```

Depending upon your regional settings, you might need to use ; instead of , in the formula.

Now for convenience set the font color same as cell color. Mostly white. So the numbers will be invisible.

Select the set of cells from say F4:F10 and apply Conditional Formatting --> Icon Sets of your choice. I have selected Green, Yellow, Red.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was writing an equivalent answer :) +1